# What is the meaning of ^{...} in ".hamlet" files

Tags: haskell, yesod, shakespeare-text

In this ".hamlet" code I would like to know what is the meaning of `^{copyright}` line

```html
$doctype 5
<html>
    <head>
        <title>#{pageTitle} - My Site
        <link rel=stylesheet href=@{Stylesheet}>
    <body>
        <h1 .page-title>#{pageTitle}
        <p>Here is a list of your friends:
        $if null friends
            <p>Sorry, I lied, you don't have any friends.
        $else
            <ul>
                $forall Friend name age <- friends
                    <li>#{name} (#{age} years old)
        <footer>^{copyright}
```

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation for Hamlet](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates). It should answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

That example you have been linked might be slightly confusing because you don't see the `copyright` function anywhere. `copyright` is just another function. You can use the `^{..}` function to embed another widget within one. This example might help you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-13.19 script

{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}

import Text.Blaze.Html
import Text.Blaze.Html.Renderer.Text (renderHtml)
import Text.Hamlet

hello ::  Html
hello = [shamlet|
<body>
    <p>Hello world
    ^{copyRight}
|]

copyRight :: Html
copyRight = [shamlet|
<p>Copyright by the SPJ
|]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let txt = renderHtml hello
  print txt
```

And on executing it:

```
$ stack hamlet.hs
"<body><p>Hello world</p>\n<p>Copyright by the SPJ</p>\n</body>\n"
```

I would recommend you to go through the [widgets chapter](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/widgets) to get a better understanding of this.